# Grouping a List with XSLT 1.0 on each single Day based on a Date-Field within the List

Tags: sorting, xslt, grouping

I have the below XML as Example and want to get this result:

```
20.06.2016
    08:30-09:00   TEST_PHX_88
    09:30-10:00   TEST_PHX_99
21.06.2016
    10:30-11:30   TEST_PHX_66
23.06.2018
    09:30-10:00   TEST_PHX_77
    09:30-10:30   TEST_PHX_55
```

So the list should get grouped by day and within the day sorted by the Time within the Date

Could someone provide me a XSL 1.0 Example to do this?

Many Thx!
Laurent

```
<XML_DATA>
    <GROUPID>1</GROUPID>
    <SRO_IF_POLYTERMINE_PRO_PATIENT>
      <XRO_PATNAME>TEST_PHX_99</XRO_PATNAME>
      <TRMBEGIN_Q>20.06.2018 09:30:00</TRMBEGIN_Q>
      <TRMENDE_Q>20.06.2018 10:00:00</TRMENDE_Q>
    </SRO_IF_POLYTERMINE_PRO_PATIENT>
    <SRO_IF_POLYTERMINE_PRO_PATIENT>
      <XRO_PATNAME>TEST_PHX_88</XRO_PATNAME>
      <TRMBEGIN_Q>20.06.2018 08:30:00</TRMBEGIN_Q>
      <TRMENDE_Q>20.06.2018 09:00:00</TRMENDE_Q>
    </SRO_IF_POLYTERMINE_PRO_PATIENT>
    <SRO_IF_POLYTERMINE_PRO_PATIENT>
      <XRO_PATNAME>TEST_PHX_77</XRO_PATNAME>
      <TRMBEGIN_Q>23.06.2018 09:30:00</TRMBEGIN_Q>
      <TRMENDE_Q>23.06.2018 10:00:00</TRMENDE_Q>
    </SRO_IF_POLYTERMINE_PRO_PATIENT>
    <SRO_IF_POLYTERMINE_PRO_PATIENT>
      <XRO_PATNAME>TEST_PHX_66</XRO_PATNAME>
      <TRMBEGIN_Q>21.06.2018 10:30:00</TRMBEGIN_Q>
      <TRMENDE_Q>21.06.2018 11:30:00</TRMENDE_Q>
    </SRO_IF_POLYTERMINE_PRO_PATIENT>
    <SRO_IF_POLYTERMINE_PRO_PATIENT>
      <XRO_PATNAME>TEST_PHX_55</XRO_PATNAME>
      <TRMBEGIN_Q>23.06.2018 09:30:00</TRMBEGIN_Q>
      <TRMENDE_Q>23.06.2018 10:30:00</TRMENDE_Q>
    </SRO_IF_POLYTERMINE_PRO_PATIENT>
</XML_DATA>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using XSLT 1.0, you will have to use a technique called as [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

For this requirement, a composite key will be defined comprising of the `date` part of string of elements `<TRMBEGIN_Q>` and `<TRMENDE_Q>`.

```
<xsl:key name="keyDate" match="SRO_IF_POLYTERMINE_PRO_PATIENT" use="concat(substring(TRMBEGIN_Q, 1, 10), '|', substring(TRMENDE_Q, 1, 10))" />
```

Next, a `for-each` loop is run for the grouped elements and within this grouping, the elements are sorted on the composite keys, so that `21.06.2018` appears before `23.06.2018`.

```
<xsl:for-each select="SRO_IF_POLYTERMINE_PRO_PATIENT[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyDate',concat(substring(TRMBEGIN_Q, 1, 10), '|', substring(TRMENDE_Q, 1, 10)))[1])]">
    <xsl:sort select="substring(key('keyDate', concat(substring(TRMBEGIN_Q, 1, 10), '|', substring(TRMENDE_Q, 1, 10)))/TRMBEGIN_Q, 1, 10)" />
    ....
</xsl:for-each>
```

Last step is to loop within the `key` to extract the individual values of the elements within the group. In this loop, a sorting on the `time` part has been applied.

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('keyDate', concat(substring(TRMBEGIN_Q, 1, 10), '|', substring(TRMENDE_Q, 1, 10)))">
    <xsl:sort select="substring(TRMBEGIN_Q, 12, 5)" />
    ....
</xsl:for-each>
```

Below is the complete XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:key name="keyDate" match="SRO_IF_POLYTERMINE_PRO_PATIENT" use="concat(substring(TRMBEGIN_Q, 1, 10), '|', substring(TRMENDE_Q, 1, 10))" />

    <xsl:template match="XML_DATA">
        <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
            <xsl:for-each select="SRO_IF_POLYTERMINE_PRO_PATIENT[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyDate',concat(substring(TRMBEGIN_Q, 1, 10), '|', substring(TRMENDE_Q, 1, 10)))[1])]">
                <xsl:sort select="substring(key('keyDate', concat(substring(TRMBEGIN_Q, 1, 10), '|', substring(TRMENDE_Q, 1, 10)))/TRMBEGIN_Q, 1, 10)" />
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <b><xsl:value-of select="substring(key('keyDate', concat(substring(TRMBEGIN_Q, 1, 10), '|', substring(TRMENDE_Q, 1, 10)))/TRMBEGIN_Q, 1, 10)" /></b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('keyDate', concat(substring(TRMBEGIN_Q, 1, 10), '|', substring(TRMENDE_Q, 1, 10)))">
                    <xsl:sort select="substring(TRMBEGIN_Q, 12, 5)" />
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(TRMBEGIN_Q, 12, 5), ' - ', substring(TRMENDE_Q, 12, 5))" /></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="XRO_PATNAME" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This generates a HTML table which looks like below.

[image: Output HTML Table]

Comment: You saved my live :) Thank you it works like a charm